# voidlinux: what packages are in repositories

Tags: repository, void-linux

I am an experienced Ubuntu user, just starting with voidlinux.
When I try to install my favourite applications, Kate and Pinta are "not found".
Kate is a sophisticated text editor. 
Pinta is a subset of gimp with only photographic tools.

**How do I find out what alternative packages are available?**
I guessed gedit, but it has changed to a new version with no title bar, very odd Open navigation, no Save As (?), no Help > About, and no accept password for saving root-owned files. Simply unusable.
This is so important it might stop me from using voidlinux, which is otherwise quite good.

Answer (score 3):

First, if packages are not in the repository you can still install them. Just follow the instructions that the package distributors provide. If you attempt to install one of the packages manually and run into some issues then post it here for additional help.

Regarding Void, it has a lot of packages. So make sure to enable the appropriate repositories and query them. I prefer to query for packages from the command line with xbps but you can also go here:
https://voidlinux.org/packages/

You can see that Kate is available in the ports tree:
https://github.com/void-linux/void-packages/tree/master/srcpkgs/kate5

Also, if you are inexperienced Void might not be the best, since the documentation is limited. A better transition might be Arch and then Void.